# Piano fingering for left hand figure

Tags: piano, technique, fingering

What would be the generally recommended fingering for the following left hand figure?

[image]

(5-2-1-3-2-3-1-2 works nicely starting on a white key, but not so much on a black key.)

Thanks!

Comment: (Hehehe. Your username has me thinking about the raised eyebrow on "haiduc" in "Dragostea din tei.")

Comment: It would be useful to see the accompanying r.h. clef along with the preceding and following bars - what comes before and after may mean changing the first and last notes' fingerings.

Comment: (You're right, Andy - I actually took it from Dragostea din tei ;)

Comment: Good points, Tim. This is not from a finished piece of music but rather a pattern that I want to use for improvisation, so applications will vary.

Answer (score 2):

I would use 5-2-1-2-1-2-1-2, but I might also experiment with 5-1-3-2-1-2-3-1. The choice would depend on 1) speed; 2) pedaling; 3) articulation; 4) what the right hand is doing at the time.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your reply. Both options make sense. Right now I'm thinking of using it in a ballad/nocturne setting, i.e. moderate tempo with a slow legato melody in the right hand and quite a bit of pedaling.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is 5-2-1-3-2-3-1-2, which allows the hand to move less... which could be relevant, depending on phrasing. That is, for some people having the 3 and 2 cross over is easier than moving the hand to let the thumb get the top note in this pattern.

Comment: Great point. Yes, folding the hand and using the thumb as a pivot feels more natural to me. But that may be because I've practiced that motion more. I will experiment with both.